# Ruby Method Chaining intermediary value

Tags: ruby, block, chain

```
irb(main):001:0> def foo(x)
irb(main):002:1> x * 10
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> def bar(y)
irb(main):005:1> y + 3
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> foo(10).tap{|x| bar(x)}
=> 100
```

I was hoping this method would allow for the chaining of methods without assigning local variables, i.e. to return 103 instead of 100. What's going on here?

Comment: The point of `tap` is not allow you to insert code into a method chain without changing it. It returns `self`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [the `tap` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-tap) can clear it up?

> Yields x to the block, and then returns x. The primary purpose of this method is to “tap into” a method chain, in order to perform operations on intermediate results within the chain.

You want it to return `y`, but it doesn't do that, it returns `x` back to the chain.

It's effectively doing:

```
def tap(x)
  yield x
  x
end
```

Comment: Ah! How would one return 'y' to a similar effect?

Answer (score 1):

Your `bar` method takes `y` and returns `y+3` but it doesn't attempt to modify `y`. For `bar` to have the effect you want it to have, it needs to modify its argument.
Sadly, numbers are immutable in ruby. You can assign a different number to a variable (i.e., a different object (i.e., with a different `object_id`)), but you can't change the original object.
If you use mutable object such as strings and let `bar` do something that mutates the string that gets passed in, then you can use your `tap` construct:

```
def foo(x)
  x*10
end

def bar(y)
  y << '3'
end

foo('a').tap{|x| bar(x)} #=> "aaaaaaaaaa3"
```

For objects like numbers, you can use classical procedural chaining [`bar(foo(10))`].